# Javascript Jquery function undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi this is my codes in a js page with this name script.js

```
    (function ($) {
    myfunc()
    {
        //some jquery codes 
    }
}
```

and I use this function in a html page like this

```
    <html>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
<button id='btnSent'>sent</button>
<script>
    (function ($) {
         $('#btns').click(function () {
            myfunc();
         })
    }(jQuery));
</script>
</html>
```

but in console i have an myfunc is undifined error

Answer (score 1):

`myfunc` is not global - it's only visible inside of the upper `(function ($) {` block, due to ordinary Javascript scoping rules. Try using just one (outer) function instead, that way anything else in the inner block would be able to see the `myfunc` which is also in the inner block:

```
(function ($) {
  function myfunc(){
    //some jquery codes 
  }
  $('#btns').click(function () {
    myfunc();
  })
}(jQuery));
```

If you *have* to keep the functionality separate for some reason, you could have `script.js` assign to a `window` variable:

```
(function ($) {
  window.myfunc = function() {
    //some jquery codes 
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using IIFEs in both cases. The scope of myfunc() is inside the IIFE in your script.js and not in the global scope.
Hence you cant access it from the  IIFE in your html.
Either don't use an IIFE in your script.js just have,

```
function myfunc(jQuery)
    {
        //some jquery codes 
    }
```

or have the myfunc() inside your IIFE in **script** tag.
This will be helpful for you to understand better about [IIFEs](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html)